# Can i add assertions for exceptions in soapui

Tags: soapui

In soapui i am able to add assertions for HTTP Status Codes.But unable to add assertions for exceptions.Is there any chance to add exceptions to assertionsIf possible please let me know how can i add.

Comment: what do you mean by exceptions? Can you add a sample exception to your question?To generally answer your question, yes you can check **almost** anything using a groovy assertion but to give you any more details I need to know what exceptions are you talking about

Answer (score 0):

An Exception from a webservice is still just a Response, (usually) with an HTTP status > 399 and the body is just plain XML. If not, SoapUI will always internally try to convert it for you to look like XML. As you mentioned you can assert a particular HTTP status, and the expected exception you can assert with just a plain [XPath assertion](http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/xpath-and-xquery-assertions.html), same as any other XML message.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @SiKing, Exception is also a valid response for any soap request and we can check the status code returned from the response.

I have done in my test cases.

Contains Assertion as

```
<responseCode>nnn</responseCode>
```

nnn - could be any return code which you know that a valid exception

Thanks